# how to parse selected values from nested json using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to parse only a selected elements from nested json.

below is my json file

```html
{
"creation-date": "Fri Mar 23 07:03:31 UTC 2018",
  "scan-with-high-privileges": true,
  "system-infos": {
 
    "hostname": "vmDiscovery",
    "domain": "aw4gb5ukuefulow5njy3bfktkc.rx.internal.cloudapp.net",
    "os": "",
    "os-details": {
      "kernel-version": "Linux vmDiscovery 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Jan 14 10:36:03 EST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux",
      "lsb-id": "",
      "lsb-version-compliance": "",
      "lsb-description": "",
      "lsb-release": "",
      "lsb-codename": ""
    }
    }
```

I am trying to access only hostname and domain from system infos. And i only read a json file from local machine and not insert the complete file.

Below is my code i tried

```html
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open("C:\\Users\\esrilka\\Documents\\jsonFiles\\jsonFiles\\Mynew.json") as fi:
    d = json.load(fi)
    works_data3=pd.DataFrame(data=d['system-infos'],columns=['hostname','domain'])
```

I get an error to pass through the index aswell.

Expected output is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7f3K.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why you want to get this into pandas. You only have two columns with one value for each of them.

Also, the pandas json loader isn't really designed to get data from your ad hoc JSON files, but to load more regular ones.

I would extract the data I wanted and load that into pandas if you really need to. Basically this just makes a new dictionary using a dictionary comprehension to load into pandas with the two fields you are interested in, then loads that.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('main.json', 'rb') as f:
    s = f.read()
    d = json.loads(s)
    d = { k: [d['system-infos'][k]] for k in ['hostname', 'domain'] }
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    print(df)
```